# A kind of coupon collector's problem

Tags: probability, distributions, mean, coupon-collector-problem

I have been struggling to find and understand the solution for a problem that I have.

[image]
Here is a [link](https://infogalactic.com/info/Coupon_collector%27s_problem) I referenced for this problem. Here's a proposed solution that I was able to find:

> Let CC(n) = the expected number of days to collect n coupouns. Number
> of days between coupon j and j+1 is CC(j+1) - CC(j). Then to collect
> all c types is CC(c).

The problem is that I don't understand how I could start formulating a solution using this. I have been trying to understand it when I'm not occupied with my other subjects, but I am just too bad at math to get it. I would really appreciate it if anyone could guide me through the solution and help me get better at this.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the problem rather than posting a photograph of it. Then your question would be self contained.

Comment: That's my bad. I edited my post.

Comment: Search our site for [tag:coupon-collector-problem] to see many examples of similar problems and how they are formulated and solved.